# Most efficient way to determine output format in PHP

Tags: php

Given three optional variables that can either be a number or `null`, as such:

```php
$length;
$width;
$height;
```

And the desired output will depend on how many of the variables are not null:

```php
// Only one variable:
echo '{$width}"';

// Two variables:
echo '{$width}" x {$height}"';

// All three variables:
echo '{$length}" x {$width}" x {$height}"';
```

What is the best way to go about printing the correct format if we don't know which of the variables has data and which are null ahead of time?

It seems like doing a multi-nested `if` would be unnecessarily cumbersome and that there should be a more elegant method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short, but maybe not the most efficient, would be to add all of the items to an array (with a default of null) and then use `array_filter` to remove nulls (note that it will also remove 0's, but with measurements that probably won't be a problem.)

Then `implode()` the result with `" x`  as a separator.  Finally add `"` to the end

```
$width = 10;
$length = 20;
$height = 5;

echo implode('" x ', array_filter([$length ?? null, $width ?? null, $height ?? null])).'"';
```

gives

```
20" x 10" x 5"
```

with

```
$width = 10;
//$length = 20;
$height = 5;
```

it gives

```
10" x 5"
```

Comment: I like this one-line solution. Thank you, @Nigel.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. Here's a reusable function using filter and mapping. The mapping bit would allow you to extend the output to include the 'l,w,h' qualifiers.

```
$l = null;
$w = 3;
$h = 4;
function getMeasurements($length, $width, $height) {
    $values = array($length, $width, $height);
    $n = array("length", "width", "height");
    echo implode(" x " ,array_filter(array_map(function($a, $index) use ($n) { return $a ? $a .'" ' . $n[$index] : "" ;},$values,array_keys($values))));


}

$measurement = getMeasurement($l, $w, $h);
// returns 3" width x 4" height

$measurement = getMeasurement(null, 5, null);
// returns 5" width
```